# ps -l: regex to show only niceness

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I need help extracting the niceness level of a process using sed regex.

#### Rough example of output

```bash
ps -l 4411
<stuff*> NI <*stuff>
<stuff*> 19 <*stuff>
```

#### The question

I'd like to get the NI and 19.

I have no idea how to get both the NI and 19, currently I have:

```bash
ps -l 4411 | \
sed s'#.*\(NI\).*#\1#'g
NI
<*numbers*>
```

which of course only gets me 'NI' I have no idea how to extract the bottom of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid the use of `sed` or any other command line tool like `awk`. You can use the same `ps` command to specify the column:

```
ps -o ni 4411
#or 
ps -o nice 4411
```

This will show something like this:

```
 NI
 19
```

If you do really want to use a command line tool then  you should use `awk`.

**awk**

If `ps -l 4411` returns this:

```
F S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI ADDR SZ WCHAN  TTY        TIME CMD
0 S  1000 22150  4822  0  80   0 -  2773 sigsus pts/4      0:01 /bin/zsh
```

then you should get the 8th column `NI` by using:

```bash
ps -l 22150 | awk '{print $8}'
```

Comment: I was trying this but done `ps -o ni -l 4411`, thanks a lot